# How to create link to Outlook with to and subject fields prefilled?

Tags: outlook

Is there a way to link to Outlook opening a new compose window with the `to` and `subject` fields pre-filled?

Below does not work:

https://outlook.live.com/mail/compose?subject=bla

Answer (score 1):

You could probably try this. It opens compose correctly for me on browser.

```
https://outlook.live.com/mail/0/deeplink/compose?to=test@gmail.com&subject=test&body=testing
```

Answer (score -1):

Outklook.com? No. Outlook the Windows client? Sure: `mailto:user@example.com?subject=test%20subject`

To open desktop Outlook, run the following from command line. I don't think you can specify subject or body, only the email:

```
outlook.exe /c ipm.note /m test@domain.demo
```

Comment: This will open the default mail client, not outlook specifically

Comment: That is correct. See the updated answer for the desktop Outlook command line options.